# Automate merging a csv file to a postgres table with different columns

Tags: postgresql, pandas, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I have a master Postgres table:

```
visitIp        userId   idSite
10.12.0.1       a       35
10.12.0.1       a       35
10.12.0.1       b       35
24.222.206.154  b       35
```

I have a new csv file that is generated every day but with different columns. Only column 'visitIp' and idSite' are same. Sometimes they have an additional column like 'action'. Is there a way to merge them into the table and automate the process. An example csv file is :

```
visitIp       action    idSite
10.12.0.1         1      35
10.12.0.1         2      35
24.222.206.154    1      35
```

So after merging it should be like:

```
visitIp        userId   idSite  action
10.12.0.1        a        35    
10.12.0.1        a        35    
10.12.0.1        b        35    
24.222.206.154   b        35    
10.12.0.1                 35     1
10.12.0.1                 35     2
24.222.206.154            35     1
```

I tried the COPY command and import using PGadmin. Did not work. Also is there a way t automate the process. Any idea would be really helpful. New to Postgres

Comment: `import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/postgres')
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Diku/Desktop/Book3.csv')
df.to_sql("table4", engine)`

Comment: Add what you have done to the question- so SO folks can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Linux - command line:**

1. Open a new text file and name it as test.sql

   vi test.sql
2. Copy the following contents and paste into test.sql

> ```
> DROP TABLE csvfile1;
> DROP TABLE csvfile2;
> DROP TABLE master;
>
> CREATE TABLE master(visitip inet, userID varchar, action integer, idsite integer);
>
> INSERT INTO master(visitip , action, idsite) VALUES('10.12.0.1', 1, 35);
> INSERT INTO master(visitip , action, idsite) VALUES('10.12.0.1', 2, 35);
> INSERT INTO master(visitip , action, idsite) VALUES('24.222.206.154', 1, 35);
>
> CREATE TABLE csvfile1(visitip inet, userID varchar, action integer, idsite integer) INHERITS (master);
>
> COPY csvfile1(visitip,userid,idsite) FROM '/tmp/csvfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
>
> CREATE TABLE csvfile2(visitip inet, userID varchar, action integer, idsite integer) INHERITS (master);
>
> COPY csvfile2(visitip,userid,idsite) FROM '/tmp/csvfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
>
> SELECT * FROM master;
> SELECT * FROM csvfile1;
> SELECT * FROM csvfile2;
> ```

3. Save and exit from the file

   :wq
4. Open a terminal and login as postgres user (or owner of database cluster)
5. Execute the sql script

   psql -f test.sql

**2. PGADMIN:**

1. Open the SQL query tool
2. Copy and paste the contents of test.sql and make sure the path of csvfile is correct. Yours may be different from what I have in the COPY command.
3. Execute query by clicking the green right triangle in tool bar menu.

Your csvfile.csv contains

> "10.12.0.1",a,35
>
> "10.12.0.1",a,35
>
> "10.12.0.1",b,35
>
> "24.222.206.154",b,35

**OUTPUT:**

```
postgres=# select * from master;
    visitip     | userid | action | idsite 
----------------+--------+--------+--------
 10.12.0.1      |        |      1 |     35
 10.12.0.1      |        |      2 |     35
 24.222.206.154 |        |      1 |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | b      |        |     35
 24.222.206.154 | b      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | b      |        |     35
 24.222.206.154 | b      |        |     35
(11 rows)

postgres=# select * from csvfile1;
    visitip     | userid | action | idsite 
----------------+--------+--------+--------
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | b      |        |     35
 24.222.206.154 | b      |        |     35
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from csvfile2;
    visitip     | userid | action | idsite 
----------------+--------+--------+--------
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | a      |        |     35
 10.12.0.1      | b      |        |     35
 24.222.206.154 | b      |        |     35
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I will try this and get back.

Comment: Use ONLY keyword to display contents of master table. SELECT * FROM ONLY master;   Refer: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html